# Lodash merge two objects but replace the same key values with new object value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have two objects with some common keys but different values like below.

```
const object1 = { 
  name: 'John',
  age: 23,
  books: ['book1', 'book2']
};

const object2 = { 
  name: 'John',
  age: 23,
  books: ['book3'],
  city: 'London'
};
```

I need the desired output as follows

```
object3 = { 
  name: 'John',
  age: 23,
  books: ['book3'],
  city: 'London'
};
```

When I do the merge using lodash as below

```
object3 = _.merge(object1 , object2);
```

the output I am getting is

```
const object3 = { 
  name: 'John',
  age: 23,
  books: ['book1','book2','book3'],
  city: 'London'
};
```

How can I replace the books array with the new data from object2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lodash is trying to be helpful by recursively merging subobjects

> This method is like _.assign except that it recursively merges own and inherited enumerable string keyed properties of source objects into the destination object. Source properties that resolve to undefined are skipped if a destination value exists. ***Array and plain object properties are merged recursively.*** Other objects and value types are overridden by assignment. Source objects are applied from left to right. Subsequent sources overwrite property assignments of previous sources.

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge (emphasis mine)

If you don't want this to happen, just use the standard ES6 [spread operator `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const object1 = { 
  name: 'John',
  age: 23,
  books: ['book1', 'book2']
};

const object2 = { 
  name: 'John',
  age: 23,
  books: ['book3'],
  city: 'London'
};

object3 = {...object1, ...object2};
object4 = Object.assign({}, object1, object2);

console.log(object3);
console.log(object4);
```

```css
/* make the Stack Overflow console bigger */ .as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh !important; }
```